# How to code a URL HTTP Get with Groovy considering inaccesible or down servers?

Tags: api, http, groovy

I am implementing an API call to the MailChimp API in my web application. But this question is valid for any call to an API which accepts a simple HTTP GET.

I would like to catch any errors and allow my application to continue without issues even if the API call failed, The mailchimp servers and down, slow or unavailable.

[MailChimp API](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/) Returns a serialized JSON Object. This is my code.

```
def listSubscribe = { apiurl, apikey, listid, email ->
    def url = "${apiurl}?method=listSubscribe&apikey=${apikey}&id=${listid}&email_address=${email}"
}
try {
   def url =  new URL(listSubscribe(apiUrl,apiKey,listId,email))
   return (url.text == 'true') ? true : false
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return false
} catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
        return false
}
```

Should I perform any other try/catch? How can I improve my code to make it safer for inaccesible API calls?

## Solution

In order to make the call asynchronous and since I am using this code inside a Grails application I created a [Quartz Job](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-quartz/guide/index.html) to execute the service containing the API Call.

```
class MailChimpListSubscribeJob {
    def mailChimpService 

    def execute(context) {
         mailChimpService.listSubscribe(context.mergedJobDataMap.get('email'))       
     }
}
```

The Service now uses a timeout and catches the generic Exception:

```
class MailChimpService {
    def grailsApplication

    def listSubscribe(email_address) {
        def apiurl = grailsApplication.config.mailchimp.apiUrl
        def apikey = grailsApplication.config.mailchimp.apiKey
        def listid = grailsApplication.config.mailchimp.listId
        listSubscribe(apiurl, apikey, listid, email_address)
    }

    def listSubscribe(apiurl, apikey, listid, email) {
        try {
            def cmdurl = "${apiurl}?method=listSubscribe&apikey=${apikey}&id=${listid}&email_address=${email}"
            def url =  new URL(cmdurl)
            def response = url.getText(connectTimeout: 4 * 1000, readTimeout: 4  * 1000)
            return (response == 'true') ? true : false  
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                return false
        } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
            return false
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

And inside my controllers:

```
MailChimpListSubscribeJob.triggerNow([email: 'myemail@example.com'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergio - You may also want to do the following:

1. Enable timeout on this call in case you don't get any response from their system in a few seconds.  This will take care of the events when their system is slow to respond, or offline.
2. If it's not a critical call that determines whether you can proceed with the rest of the code execution, then you should also consider making it asynchronous.
3. Catch the generic Exception as well in case you want to handle any unforeseen runtime exceptions that may occur.

Comment: how can i enable a timeout with URL class? Do i need to use a class such as http-builder? http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/

Comment: Check this blog: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/09/groovy-goodness-use-connection.html

Comment: Thanks for the link explaining the timeout